# Crear Llave Foranea en tabla con datos MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando crear una Llave foránea en una tabla que ya tiene datos, el problema es que me muestra el error **#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**. La única forma que manejo es eliminar la información y después crear la llave.
Mi consulta es si hay alguna forma de crear la llave con datos en la tabla ya que la BD esta en producción??

Mi base de datos es MYSQL.

Comment: Trata de proveer por favor un [mcve]

Comment: Si se puede crear la FK en tablas que tienen datos. El problema parece ser que en la tabla de la FK tenes un registro que no tiene referencia en la otra tabla. Ej: Como tener renglones de factura y que no exista la cabecera de la misma.

Comment: Escribí la FK y te muestro cono encontrar esos registros "huérfanos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta crear el campo de la FK de tal forma que admita valores `NULL`, crea la tabla de referencia con todos los valores que referencies y, en ese momento, defines la clave ajena. No debería darte ningún problema.

Éste sería el dataset de partida:

```
CREATE TABLE viajeros(
  id_viajero int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  viajero varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE viajan(
  id_viaje int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  destino varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO viajeros (viajero) VALUES
  ('Juan'),('Pedro'),('Lucas'),('Amparo');
INSERT INTO viajan (destino) VALUES
  ('Atenas'),('Madrid'),('París');
```

Si ahora creas el campo `id_viajero` de forma que no admita valores `NULL` e intentas crear la FK:

```
ALTER TABLE viajan ADD id_viajero int NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE viajan ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_viajero) 
  REFERENCES viajeros(id_viajero);
```

Obtendrás el error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Sin embargo, si pones todos esos valores a `NULL`, en vez de a `0`:

```
ALTER TABLE viajan MODIFY id_viajero int NULL;
UPDATE viajan set id_viajero=NULL;
```

Ahora sí que te permitirá crear la clave ajena en producción:

```
ALTER TABLE viajan ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_viajero) 
  REFERENCES viajeros(id_viajero);
```

Comment: Ok, gracias, espero tu ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono enseguida.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya esta inicializada la BD, te dará eseproblema, al menos que borres la tabla y la vuelvas a crear, ya que como ya esta definida, te dará ese error